# Generate dotcover coverage report with jenkins

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, .net-core, dotnet-cli, dotcover

I have ci server setup on jenkins which builds the .net core 2.2 application. and then generates Test Coverage report using dotcover.

I am executing following command from jenkins job to generate coverage report using dotcover in the directory where Test project's .csproj file exist.

```
dotnet restore

dotnet dotcover test --dcReportType=HTML --dcOutPut="%WORKSPACE%\TestReport\index.html"
```

It gives me following error.

> [JetBrains dotCover] Failed to perform coverage analysis. Operation
> was canceled by the user.
>
> Failed to register x86 core COM object: RegSvr32 failed to register
> the core. Exit code is 00000003. Probably you haven't rebooted after a
> Windows update. Please reboot the computer and try again.

I have already updated and rebooted as suggested in error but it doesn't solves the issue.

If I run this command directly from Command Line it works fine and generates report properly with the same commands.

Don't know what I am missing in jenkins.

Comment: Try to install updates and reboot PC, as suggested

Comment: I have tried that it does not solves the error.